# apt is broken and the fix is too because of too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/diversions'

Tags: apt, dpkg

I installed the RPi os lite using the imager and it boots up and all but I can't install packages:

```
$ sudo apt install sl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 75 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/diversions'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Neither can I upgrade (same error is thrown with `sudo apt upgrade`)

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  userconf-pi
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files bash cifs-utils curl dirmngr distro-info-data dphys-swapfile dpkg dpkg-dev firmware-atheros firmware-brcm80211 firmware-libertas firmware-misc-nonfree
  firmware-realtek gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv gzip libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc-l10n libc6 libc6-dbg
  libc6-dev libcamera-apps-lite libcamera0 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libdpkg-perl libexpat1 libfreetype-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libfribidi0 libgnutls30 libldap-2.4-2
  liblzma5 libntfs-3g883 libpam-chksshpwd libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi0
  libssl1.1 libwbclient0 libxml2 locales logrotate nano ntfs-3g openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server openssl pi-bluetooth raspi-config rpi-eeprom rsyslog ssh tzdata
  wireless-regdb xz-utils
74 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/89.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 8,944 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/diversions'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Both of these errors are about this `/var/lib/dpkg/diversions`. When researching this I found people for whom `sudo dpkg --configure -a` fixed it put for me that returns this

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/diversions'
```

Comment: Did you update BEFORE trying?

Comment: DO NOT ever use apt-get - just use apt!

Comment: Please include the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/diversions` in your question.  Why not edit and correct the file?